# AWS ec2 to run a python program using latex and OpenCV

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cluster-computing

A friend and I are working on a machine learning project together. We've managed to collect about 5,000 tex documents (we hope to get up to around 100,000 soon). We have a python script that we run on each document to do some text manipulation, extract particular parts of the tex code, compile the parts, convert the compiled parts to cropped PNG images, and search a converted PNG of the full tex for the cropped images using OpenCV. The code takes between 30 seconds and 2 minutes on the documents we've tried so far, so we really need to speed it up.

I've been tasked with gaining access to a computer cluster and figuring out how to implement our code on such a cluster. Someone suggested I look into using AWS, so I've made an account and have been trying to figure out how to use EC2 for the past few hours. Am I on the right track, or is there some other part of AWS or something else entirely that would be better suited to my task?

Whatever I use, it has to have access to the various python libraries in our code and to pdflatex and the full set of tex packages. Is this possible on EC2? I have almost no idea how to go about using EC2 (I've managed to start some instances, but how do I use them to run my script? and do I need to change my python script to accomodate the parallel processing, or does EC2 take care of that somehow? is it as easy as starting a linux instance and installing the programs I need like I would on any other linux machine?). None of the tutorials are immediately useful, and I'm still not even sure if EC2 is capable of doing what I'm looking for. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't normally answer this kind of question but it sounds like you are doing something interesting.   So let's have a go

Q1.

> "We have a python script that we run on each document to do some text
>   manipulation, extract particular parts of the tex code, compile the
>   parts, convert the compiled parts to cropped PNG images, and search a
>   converted PNG of the full tex for the cropped images using OpenCV.. we
>   really need to speed it up"

Probably you could split the 100,000 documents into 10 parts and set up 
10 instances of the processing software and do the run in parallel.

To set up 10 instances the same, there are many methods but one of the simpler ways is to set up one machine as desired, take a snapshot, make an AMI and then
use the AMI to launch many more copies.

There might be an extra step with putting the results of the search into some
kind of central database.

I don't know anything about OpenCV but there are several suggestions that with a G3 instance type (this has a GPU) it might go faster.  Google for "Open CV on AWS"

Q2.

> "trying to figure out how to use EC2 for the past few hours. Am I on
>   the right track, or is there some other part of AWS or something else
>   entirely that would be better suited to my task?"

EC2 is a general purpose virtual machine, so if you already have code that runs on
some other machine it is easy to move it to EC2
EC2 has many features but one you might find interesting is "spot instances", these are short lived but cheap ( typically 10% of the price ) instance launch

Q3.

> Whatever I use, it has to have access to the various python libraries
>   in our code and to pdflatex and the full set of tex packages. Is this
>   possible on EC2?

Yes, they will pip install or install from packages just like any other system

Q4.

> how do I use them to run my script? and do I need to change my python
>   script to accomodate the parallel processing, or does EC2 take care of
>   that somehow? is it as easy as starting a linux instance and
>   installing the programs I need like I would on any other linux
>   machine?

As described above your basic task seems to scale well, you may need a step to
collate the results.  Yes it is basically the same as any other linux machine